# jquery программно открыть select

Tags: jquery

```
<label class="select-parent">
   <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
      <option value="">Msk</option>
      <option value="">Spb</option>
   </select>
</label>
```

Нужно что бы при клике на `select-parent` выпадал `select`. Как это сделать?

Если делаю так:

```
$(".select-parent").click(function () {
   $(this).find("select").trigger("click");
});
```

Получается бесконечная рекурсия, и выводит ошибку переполнения стека.

Что бы не было рекурсивного вызова, пробовал делать так:

```
$(".select-parent").click(function () {
   $(this).find("select").trigger("mousedown");
});
```

Т.к. select выпадает так же на событие `mousedown`

А таким образов вообще ничего не происходит.
Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему?

Comment: а он сейчас разве не выпадает?

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function() {

    $('.select-parent').click(function() {
        open($('.form-control'));
    });

});

function open(elem) {
    if (document.createEvent) {
        var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        elem[0].dispatchEvent(e);
    } else if (element.fireEvent) {
        elem[0].fireEvent("onmousedown");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select-parent">Открыть select <br/>
   <select name="" class="form-control">
      <option value="">Msk</option>
      <option value="">Spb</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

источник https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234971/simulate-click-on-select-element-with-jquery

Comment: чем это принципиально отличается от `.trigger("mousedown");`?