# Как активировать системное меню при нажатии на сторонний элемент?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Есть выпадающее обычное стилизованное меню и мобильное, реализованное при помощи тега `<select>...</select>`, на которое заменяется обычное при переходе к мобильному разрешению. Также, есть кнопка, открывающая выпадающее меню. Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на эту кнопку на телефоне активировалось системное меню (`select`)?

Comment: А картинки будут? =)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745491/trigger-default-event-on-styled-select-on-android?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: На эту тему есть готовые ответы: [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558155/jquery-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-select) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048213/open-select-using-javascript-jquery/11642008) .